# zoom/pan in Imagebox of EmguCV

Tags: image, scroll, emgucv

Does anyone know how to zoom/pan (scroll) on the imagebox of EmguCV using C# code? It works just fine using mouse scroll, But I'd like to do it using code.

I tried this, but with no luck!

```
ImageBox1.SetZoomScale(1, new Point(400, 400));
```

Answer (score 0):

With SetZoomScale you are on the right way.
Set a zoom scale grater than 1 to zoom in and a zoom scale smaller than 1 to zoom out. 1 means no zoom.
The second parameter is the center of the zoomed area relative to the image control.
So, if you start with a ZoomScale = 1 do the following:

Zoom in with fix point (400,00)

```
ImageBox1.SetZoomScale(2, new Point(400, 400));
```

Reset original zoom

```
ImageBox1.SetZoomScale(1, new Point(400, 400));
```

Zoom out with fix point (400,00)

```
ImageBox1.SetZoomScale(0.5, new Point(400, 400));
```